# AngularJS $resource 'GET' accesses the correct API, but 'PUT' and 'POST' do not

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, angularjs, angular-resource

Follow up from [AngularJS $resource calls the wrong API URL when using method:POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540139/angularjs-resource-calls-the-wrong-api-url-when-using-methodpost/19541674?noredirect=1#comment29037653_19541674)

My controller is set up like this, with Angular's `$resource`:

```
$scope.updateProduct = $resource('/api/updateProduct/:product/:param/:value',{},{
  query: {method:'GET'},
  post: {method:'POST'},
  save: {method:'PUT', params: {brand: '@brand', param:'@param', value:'@value'}},
  remove: {method:'DELETE'}
});
$scope.updateProduct.save({
    product : $scope.post._id, 
    param: 'likes', 
    value: $scope.user._id
  });
```

My server runs on `NodeJS` and `ExpressJS`. In my console, when the `save` operation is called, I can see:

```
POST /api/updateBrand/<productid>/likes/fun,%20quirky%20loud,%20boho,%20hippy 200 22ms - 2.31kb
```

However, my API is not being correctly accessed. For instance, if I go to the above URL in my browser, the API function is called, and my database is updated (and it is reported in my server's console). Yet when Angular does a `PUT` on this URL, nothing happens at all.

Interestingly, when I change `$scope.updateProduct.save()` to `$scope.updateProduct.get()`, the API is correctly called and everything works fine.

Any ideas what's going on here?

**EDIT: Here's the server setup:**

`ExpressJS` API setup:

```
 app.get('/api/updateProduct/:product/:param/:value', api.updateProduct);
```

`API code`

```
exports.updateProduct = function (req, res) {
    console.log("TEST")

    var product = req.params.product;
    var param   = req.params.param;
    var value   = req.params.value;
    var props = { $push: {} };

    if(param == 'userTags'){
        var oldVal = value;
        value = oldVal.match(/[-'"\w]+/g);
        props.$push[param];
        props.$push[param] = {$each: []};
        props.$push[param].$each = value;
    }else{
    var props = { $push: {} };
        props.$push[param] = value;       
    }
    db.products.update({"_id": ObjectId(product)}, props, function (err, record) {
        if (err || !(record)) {
            console.log("Lookup Error: " + err);
        } else{
            console.log("Updated " + product + " with " + param);
            console.log(record);
            res.json({obj:record})
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your server?

Comment: I could but it's not accessed at all, the first line is a `console.log("TEST")` and it doesn't get accessed. Again, when I do `updateProduct.get()` instead of `updateProduct.save()` it works just fine (so the `console.log()` correctly logs)

Comment: I think that your server routing might have a problem.

Comment: Alright, added it to the code above.

Comment: Where do you tell ExpressJS that exports.updateProduct is waiting for a POST or PUT? Have a look at the ExpressJS API, they refer to app.VERB(path, [callback...], callback) where verb is the method of the request. Here you tell it to wait for GET.

Comment: Ah! I'm totally new to this and definitely didn't see that. So I just need to change the express call to ` app.put('/api/updateProduct/:product/:param/:value', api.updateProduct);`? If you post it as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I am not familiar with ExpressJS, but I'm pretty sure that's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your server is not waiting for a POST or PUT request, but a GET request as per your configuration.

```
app.get('/api/updateProduct/:product/:param/:value', api.updateProduct);
```

According to the ExpressJS API (http://expressjs.com/api.html), you should be able to replace the get with any valid http verb.

```
app.VERB(path, [callback...], callback)
app.post('/api/updateProduct/:product/:param/:value', api.updateProduct);
app.put('/api/updateProduct/:product/:param/:value', api.updateProduct);
```